# Update with subquery in PostgreSQL not working

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, subquery, postgresql-9.3

I'm using Postgresql 9.3 and this SQL doesn't work :

```
UPDATE revision_table
SET (code, uuid, converted_entity1uuid, converted_entity1code) = 
         (SELECT convertedT.code, convertedT.uuid, convertedT.uuid, convertedT.code
          FROM currency convertedT 
          INNER JOIN currency_conversion_aud conversionT ON conversionT.currency1_id = convertedT.id
          WHERE conversionT.id = 125
          ORDER BY rev DESC LIMIT 1), 
    (converted_entity2uuid, converted_entity2code) = 
         (SELECT convertedT.uuid, convertedT.code 
          FROM currency convertedT 
          INNER JOIN currency_conversion_aud conversionT ON conversionT.currency2_id = convertedT.id
          WHERE conversionT.id = 125
          ORDER BY rev DESC LIMIT 1) 
WHERE id = 12;
```

Error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
>   LIGNE 3 :                     (SELECT convertedT.code, convertedT.uuid...

But if I run this SQL in postgres 9.6 it works fine:

```
UPDATE revision_table
SET (code, uuid, converted_entity1uuid, converted_entity1code) = 
         (SELECT convertedT.code, convertedT.uuid, convertedT.uuid, convertedT.code
          FROM currency convertedT 
          INNER JOIN currency_conversion_aud conversionT ON conversionT.currency1_id = convertedT.id
          WHERE conversionT.id = 12
          ORDER BY rev DESC LIMIT 1), 
    (converted_entity2uuid, converted_entity2code) = 
         (SELECT convertedT.uuid, convertedT.code 
          FROM currency convertedT 
          INNER JOIN currency_conversion_aud conversionT ON conversionT.currency2_id = convertedT.id
          WHERE conversionT.id = 12 
          ORDER BY rev DESC LIMIT 1) 
WHERE id = 12;

UPDATE 0
Temps : 75,359 ms
```

How can I convert to be compatible with 9.3 because production are in 9.3?

Thanks for help

Comment: Upgrade to Postgres 9.6, this is the easiest way.  Honestly, even 9.6 is several years old now, and probably won't be supported forever anyway.

Comment: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: the life cycle is documented here: https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Comment: You can rewrite it to a `update ... set ... from ( .... )` but your code is really hard to follow.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, i m agree but not possible for now, i have rewrite with update set from syntax and its ok thanks

Answer (score 0):

finaly solved :

```
UPDATE 
  revision_table
SET
  code = sub1.code, 
  uuid = sub1.uuid,
  converted_entity1uuid = sub1.uuid,
  converted_entity1code = sub1.code,
  converted_entity2uuid=sub2.uuid,
  converted_entity2code=sub2.code
FROM (
  SELECT convertedT.code, convertedT.uuid
  FROM currency convertedT 
  INNER JOIN currency_conversion_aud conversionT
    ON conversionT.currency1_id = convertedT.id
  WHERE conversionT.id = 12
  ORDER BY rev DESC LIMIT 1
) sub1,
(
  SELECT convertedT.uuid, convertedT.code 
  FROM currency convertedT 
  INNER JOIN currency_conversion_aud conversionT
    ON conversionT.currency2_id = convertedT.id
  WHERE conversionT.id = 12 
  ORDER BY rev DESC LIMIT 1
)  sub2
WHERE id = 12;
```